# Changing enumeration yields strange results

Tags: enumerate

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
\begin{enumerate}[{Part 1}]
\item 
\item 
\item
\end{enumerate}
```

It renders as follows:

P1rt 1

P2rt 2

P3rt 3

Why?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ and which list-related package(s) — such as `enumerate` and `enumitem` — you load.

Comment: You are loading `\usepackage{enumerate}` and not using it appropriately. As written in almost spotless English in the abstract of the package documentation: "An occurrence of one of the tokens `A` `a` `I` `i` or `1` produces the value of the counter printed with (respectively) `\Alph` `\alph` `\Roman` `\roman` or `\arabic`." This is what happens here.

Comment: @daleif low level feature the {} are dropped here as they are the whole argument....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle did not realise that (and was not at a PC so could not test)

Answer (score 3):

The result is differently strange with `enumitem` , but in both cases the solution is the same: add a pair of braces around ‘Part’:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
% \usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{Part} 1]
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\begin{enumerate}[Part 1]
\item
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is better to give the text `Part` through some tag will solve the issue, e.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumerate}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{\partname\ 1}]
\item 
\item 
\item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: Even easier `[{Part} 1]`